# Tiny MCE stripping out facebook tags

Tags: javascript, facebook, tinymce

Tiny MCE version 3, minor 4.3.2 of 6/30/2011 is stripping out the following when I click update within the source code window:

```
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/pagename/12234568990" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="200" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

as well as the XFBML version:

```
     <fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/pagename/12234568990" send="true" layout="button_count" width="200" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
```

anyone know what to edit in tiny_mce_src.js to allow custom tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to add the `<fb:*>` tags to your `tinyMCE.init` call:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    valid_elements: "fb:like"
});
```

You have to add every other valid element to that string as well. See the default ruleset here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements

However, in my experience it's never been a good idea to allow anything else than some very few elements in a RTE. I've always used another way to add elements like Facebook Like buttons etc..

Comment: That looks promising. I think it would look like this:
       (+fb:like[href|send|layout|width|show_faces]');

However, I am not finding, "tinyMCE.init({" anywhere.
does this get added to tiny_mce.js or tiny_mce_src.js or a different js file within plugins folder?

Comment: tinyMCE.init usually gets called from a js-file or a html page, it is also psossible to use an ajax call and to evaluate the answer which can contain a tinymce.init call

Answer (score 2):

found it in my admin/app/view, pages edit.
    tinyMCE.init({
    extended_valid_elements : "+fb:like[href|send|layout|width|show_faces]",
    }